# Javascript RegEx Object Double Escape Special Characters

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I've checked out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp (not that I was too hopeful) and various questions here with no luck.

What I need is a method for double escaping c# special characters within javascript:

A string that contains `"\b"` (a backspace character)

Needs to be changed to `"\\\\b"` (a.k.a. a literal `"\\b"`).

For example
`"foo_bar_\b"` needs to become `@"foo_bar_\\\\b"`

My main difficulty is simply catching the special character and 
`mystring.replace(/(\[|\])/g, '\\\\$1');` is the closest thing I've found.

Comment: [Be careful with w3schools.com!](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: If you're dealing with just single characters, use this syntax: `/([\[\]])/g`. Anyway, what's the problem with your code?

Comment: A validator just wasn't liking a `"\b"` (it's invalid .xml + etc..) character that is legitimately returned.

Comment: th match "\b" with a regex `[\b]`

Comment: Yeh, problem is what do I do for all the other escape characters, or even a single `"\"`? It'll be hard to find a better regex pattern than the one I posted unless there's something native (similar to Regex.Escape in .net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got it:

`mystring.replace(/(\\)/g, '\\\\')`

(took me long enough)